# .htaccess redirect subdomain to a subfolder of another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect the domain as following:

http://help.site.com/*
to http://anothersite.com/help/*

I dont found any instruction for exactly that purpose, only general redirection (www. to non www etc.):
http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/redirect-domain-www-subdomain.shtml

I already tried this, but it does just shows a 301 <s>error</s> message:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help\.site\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anothersite.com/help/$1 [R=301]
```

**EDIT: I changed it to this, now it works...**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help\.site\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anothersite.com/help/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That looks correct. What's the error? Never heard of a `301` error before...

Comment: There is no 301 error (codes starting with "3" aren't errors). The 301 is a permanent redirect.

Comment: The output is the following:
"Moved Permanently

The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." Its not a really 301 error, but its shows this message instead of redirect to the other domain...

Comment: You should update your question with that. The 301 is correct, that's exactly what you should get. Use a browser inspector to check the `Location` header value. It sounds like your rewrite rule is fine but you have another problem elsewhere

Comment: Your other domain is generating a 500 error, check your error logs.

Comment: Yea I updated the question. On the old domain there is no error in the log and the new page does load fine in my browser without any issue...

Comment: Solved it (see question) :) Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: @arco444 that's not totally true. He had also forgotten to use the `L` with the `R` so that can cause issues as well. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r